# Modern practices for advanced logging and log analysis?

Tags: java, logging

This question is for approaches to logging.

What to log, where to log, how to keep logs both parseable and readable, are multiline logs good or bad, text logs vs binary logs, what monitoring and analytical data can be extracted and used, how logs should be managed, how to handle logging level, how to handle volume of logs, and more and more and more....

This is quite important and hard to do right in distributed environment with lots of applications.

Strangely, I was not able to find much on topic so my experience comes from trial, error and looking at other's people code.

Good books/articles/thoughts? Anyone?

Comment: Why the downvotes?  This is a very relevant issue for modern software.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the points that you should keep in mind when logging are:

> 1. Making sense.
> 2. Informative.
> 3. Providing information in a exception block. (very important put as many information as possible in this block)
> 4. Providing the state of the application. (again very important for analysis)

Do not log any user data if possible but instead log information that relates to it like application generated ids and its status. This is the bear minimal logging. If you need to debug something then you can add debugging logs as well which you can remove before it goes to production or put it in a `if(log.isDebugEnabled())` block so that you can switch between debug, info, error etc.,